# Web Scraping Uniqlo

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and want to web scrape a website uniqlo. I want to turn this into a loop and extract product name and price, but first I want to grab one item to show this is working. However in the containers variable, I have a 0, there should be 4. Am I grabbing the wrong class? I really dont know where to go from here.

```
## diff
import bs4
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url1 = 'https://www.uniqlo.com/jp/store/feature/uq/sale/women/'

uClient = urlopen(Request(url1, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'}))
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
filename = "FemaleProducts.csv"
file = open(filename,"w",newline='')
product_list = []

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"unit 13_alias_color_chip_group alias_initialized color_chip_init"})   #Find all li with class: grid-tile
print(len(containers))
```

Comment: if you load the page, you can see the prices being loaded after a second, I have had better luck waiting for the page to load before trying to extract elements and I usually do this in selenium instead of requests/urllib+bs4

Comment: Hi Tenacious, I have never used selenium. Maybe you could provide and example for this example?

Comment: I'm able to get some decent results but I am in USA so the encoding is weird lol. Waiting 5 seconds and then getting products and prices yields results like: `"product": "\u30b3\u30c3\u30c8\u30f3\u30ab\u30b7\u30df\u30e4\u30af\u30eb\u30fc\u30cd\u30c3\u30af\u30bb\u30fc\u30bf\u30fc\uff08\u9577\u8896\uff09",
        "price": "\u00a51,290"` I will post an example in a few

Comment: Thanks Tenacious, I guess a bad example to start learning from lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

params = {
    "dispLayerInfoComingsoon": "",
    "dispLayerInfoFull": "",
    "dispLayerInfo": "/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/21,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/102,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/106,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/03,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/02,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/14,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/105,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/11,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/17,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/107,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/18,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/108,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/20,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/19,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/09",
    "_": "1589090253243"
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0",
    "Accept": "text/html, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    names = [name.get_text(strip=True) for name in soup.select("dt.name")]
    prices = [price.get_text(strip=True) for price in soup.select(
        "dd.price.fr-alias-primary--color01")]
    for items in zip(names, prices):
        print(items)


main("https://www.uniqlo.com/jp/store/feature/uq/alias/v2/ajaxAliasItem.jsp")
```

Output:

```
('ティアードスカート', '¥2,990')
('アナ スイ ソフトコットンブラウス（長袖）', '¥1,990')
('アナ スイ ソフトコットンブラウス（長袖）', '¥1,990')
('コート', '¥4,990')
('モックネックT（長袖）', '¥990')
('ベルテッドプリーツジーンズ（丈標準70cm）', '¥1,990')
('コットンリバーシブルパーカ', '¥4,990')
('ディズニー ラブ ミニー マウス コレクション バイ アンブッシュ パーカ', '¥3,990')
('ポケッタブルUVカットパーカ', '¥1,990')
('コットンパーカ', '¥2,990')
('リブブルゾン', '¥2,990')
('ロングコート', '¥4,990')
('コート', '¥4,990')
('ディズニー ラブ ミニー マウス コレクション バイ アンブッシュ コート', '¥3,990')
('ディズニー ラブ ミニー マウス コレクション バイ アンブッシュ コート', '¥3,990')
('リラックストレンチコート', '¥5,990')
('トレンチコート', '¥4,990')
('リネンコットンコート（ストライプ）', '¥2,990')
('パデットライナーモッズコート', '¥4,990')
('トラッカージャケット', '¥2,990')
('ジャージーテーラージャケット', '¥4,990')
('UVカットリラックスジャケット', '¥3,990')
('リネンコットンシャツジャケット', '¥1,990')
('ジャージーリラックスジャケット', '¥1,990')
('デニムオーバーサイズジャケット', '¥1,990')
('デニムジャケット', '¥2,990')
('コットンシャツジャケット', '¥1,990')
('パデットシャツジャケット', '¥2,990')
('パデットシャツジャケット', '¥2,990')
('ポンチラウンドネックジャケット', '¥3,990')
('ポンチラウンドネックジャケット', '¥3,990')
('ポンチラウンドネックジャケット', '¥3,990')
('ボリュームVネックロングセーター（長袖）', '¥990')
('リブモックネックセーター（長袖）', '¥1,290')
('3DコットンプリーツVネックセーター（5分袖）', '¥1,990')
('カラーミックスクルーネックセーター（長袖）', '¥990')
('シャイニーリブハイネックセーター（長袖）', '¥790')
('ライトスフレヤーンポインテールクルーネックセーター（長袖）', '¥790')
('ライトスフレヤーンリラックスクルーネックセーター（長袖）', '¥990')
('リブクルーネックセーター（半袖）', '¥1,990')
('リブクルーネックセーター（ノースリーブ）', '¥1,990')
('ミドルゲージクルーネックセーター（長袖）', '¥1,290')
('コットンカシミヤクルーネックセーター（長袖）', '¥1,290')
('UVカットスリットロングカーディガン（長袖）', '¥1,990')
('Joy of Printシフォンワンピース（7分袖）', '¥2,990')
('フィンレイソン Ｔワンピース（5分袖）', '¥1,990')
('3Dコットンリブクルーネックワンピース（半袖・ショート丈・78.5～88cm）', '¥3,990')
('3Dコットンリブクルーネックワンピース（半袖・レギュラー丈・84.5～94cm）', '¥3,990')
('3Dコットンリブクルーネックワンピース（半袖・ロング丈・90.5～100cm）', '¥3,990')
('レーヨンオープンカラーワンピース（半袖）', '¥3,990')
('コットンリネンシャツワンピース（長袖）', '¥2,990')
('リネンブレンドVネックワンピース（長袖）', '¥2,990')
('ポロワンピース（5分袖）', '¥1,990')
('ドローストリングシャツワンピース（長袖）', '¥1,990')
('デニムドローストリングワンピース（長袖）', '¥1,290')
('リネンコットンシャツワンピース（長袖）', '¥2,990')
('ディズニー・ストーリーズ スウェットワンピース（長袖）', '¥1,990')
('プリントシャツワンピース（7分袖）', '¥1,990')
('ジョーゼットプリーツワンピース（長袖）', '¥2,990')
('ベルテッドロングシャツワンピース（長袖）', '¥1,990')
('レーヨンシャツワンピース（7分袖）', '¥2,990')
('エクストラファインコットンAラインワンピース（長袖）', '¥1,990')
('レーヨンカシュクールワンピース（長袖）', '¥1,290')
('レーヨンプリントシャツワンピース（ドット・7分袖）', '¥2,990')
('クルーネックTワンピース（半袖）', '¥1,290')
('スタンドカラーシャツワンピース（7分袖）', '¥3,990')
('リネンブレンドギャザーワンピース（7分袖）', '¥2,990')
('ポンチフレアワンピース（長袖）', '¥1,990')
('アナ スイ ソフトコットンブラウス（長袖）', '¥1,990')
('アナ スイ ソフトコットンブラウス（長袖）', '¥1,990')
('アナ スイ ソフトコットンブラウス（長袖）', '¥1,990')
('ギャザーブラウス（半袖）', '¥1,990')
('ロングシャツ（長袖）', '¥2,990')
('ギャザースリーブシャツ（長袖）', '¥1,990')
('ギャザーブラウス（半袖）', '¥1,990')
('デニムオーバーサイズシャツ（長袖）', '¥1,290')
('オーバーサイズシャツ（長袖）', '¥1,290')
('オーバーサイズシャツ（長袖）', '¥1,290')
('Tブラウス（長袖）', '¥1,290')
('ジョーゼットプリーツブラウス（長袖）', '¥1,290')
('コットンリネンチュニック（長袖）', '¥2,990')
('コットンリネンチュニック（長袖）', '¥2,990')
('リネンコットンチュニック（長袖）', '¥2,990')
('コットンチュニック（長袖）', '¥2,990')
('レーヨンブラウス（長袖）', '¥990')
('ドライソフトスウェットプルパーカ（長袖）', '¥990')
('スウェットオーバーサイズプルパーカ（長袖）', '¥1,290')
('ディズニー・ストーリーズ スウェットプルパーカ（長袖）', '¥990')
('スウェットボクシークルーネックシャツ（長袖）', '¥990')
('スウェットハーフジップシャツ（長袖）', '¥990')
('リブボートネックT（長袖）', '¥500')
('マーセライズコットンシャーリングボリュームスリーブT（7分袖）', '¥990')      
('リブラウンドネックT（長袖）', '¥500')
('モックネックT（長袖）', '¥990')
('クレープジャージーチュニック（半袖）セットアップ可能', '¥1,290')
('リラックスフィットクルーネックT（半袖）', '¥500')
('美少女戦士セーラームーン UT（グラフィックTシャツ・半袖）', '¥790')
('美少女戦士セーラームーン UT（グラフィックTシャツ・半袖）', '¥790')
('ベルテッドプリーツジーンズ（丈標準70cm）', '¥1,990')
('ベルテッドプリーツジーンズ（丈長め82cm）', '¥1,990')
('ウルトラストレッチジーンズ', '¥2,990')
('ハイライズストレートジーンズ(丈標準72cm）', '¥500')
('ハイライズボーイフレンドジーンズ', '¥2,990')
('ワイドフィットカーブジーンズ（丈長め82cm）', '¥1,990')
('ワイドフィットカーブジーンズ', '¥1,990')
('ワイドフィットカーブジーンズ', '¥1,990')
('ウールブレンドワイドパンツ', '¥2,990')
('ワイドフィットカーブパンツ', '¥1,290')
('ワイドフィットカーブパンツ（丈長め78cm）', '¥1,290')
('ウルトラストレッチレギンスパンツ（丈標準69.5～71.5cm）', '¥1,290')
('ウルトラストレッチプリントレギンスパンツ（丈標準69.5～71.5cm）', '¥1,290')
('ウルトラストレッチレギンスパンツ（丈長め74.5～76.5cm）', '¥1,290')
('ウルトラストレッチプリントレギンスパンツ（丈長め74.5～76.5cm）', '¥1,290')  
('コットンツイルタックベルテッドパンツ', '¥1,990')
('ワイドフィットカーブツイルジャージーパンツ（丈標準69～71cm）', '¥1,990')    
('ワイドフィットカーブツイルジャージーパンツ（丈長め76cm）', '¥1,990')        
('カーペンターパンツ', '¥1,990')
('コットンイージーパンツ', '¥1,990')
('ツイルジャージーイージーパンツ', '¥2,990')
('パラシュートパンツ', '¥2,990')
('チノワイドパンツ', '¥2,990')
('デニムイージーアンクルパンツ', '¥2,990')
('ルーズフィットカーゴジョガーパンツ（丈標準64～66cm）', '¥990')
('ルーズフィットカーゴジョガーパンツ（丈長め71cm）', '¥990')
('ドレープリラックステーパードアンクルパンツ（丈長め74cm）', '¥1,990')        
('ドレープリラックステーパードアンクルパンツ（丈標準67～69cm）', '¥1,990')    
('ディズニー ラブ ミニー マウス コレクション バイ アンブッシュ イージーアンク 
ルパンツ', '¥1,990')
('ディズニー ラブ ミニー マウス コレクション バイ アンブッシュ イージーアンク 
ルパンツ', '¥1,990')
('ストレートアンクルパンツ', '¥1,990')
('デニムイージーショーツ', '¥1,990')
('ドライストレッチジョガーパンツ（レングス72～74ｃｍ）', '¥390')
('ティアードスカート', '¥2,990')
('ティアードスカート', '¥2,990')
('ラップスカート', '¥2,990')
('タックフレアスカート', '¥2,990')
('プリントマーメイドロングスカート（丈標準82～87cm）', '¥1,290')
('シフォンプリーツプリントロングスカート（ドット・丈標準78～82cm）', '¥1,290')
('シフォンプリーツプリントロングスカート（ドット・丈短め73～77cm）', '¥1,290')
('コットンマーメイドロングスカート（ハイウエスト・丈標準80～84cm）', '¥1,290')
('コットンマーメイドロングスカート（ハイウエスト・丈短め75～79cm）', '¥1,290')
('ドライストレッチタックフレアスカート（ハイウエスト・丈標準73～77cm）', '¥990')
('コットンマーメイドロングスカート（ハイウエスト・デニム・丈標準80～84cm）', '¥1,290')
('ドライストレッチタックフレアスカート（ハイウエスト・丈短め68～72cm）', '¥990')
('デニムジャージースカート（丈標準73.5～77.5㎝）', '¥1,290')
('レーヨンラップスカート', '¥1,990')
('レーヨンラップスカート', '¥1,990')
('レーヨンラップスカート', '¥1,990')
('コットンツイルベルテッドスカート', '¥1,990')
('ツイルジャージーラップスカート', '¥1,990')
('ライトコットンギャザースカート', '¥1,990')
('3Dコットンフレアミディスカート セットアップ可能', '¥990')
('エアリズムキャミソール（ヘザー）', '¥500')
('エアリズムブラキャミソール', '¥990')
('コンフィールタッチフラットシューズ', '¥1,990')
('ブロックテックショルダーバッグ', '¥2,990')
```

**CSV Version**:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

params = {
    "dispLayerInfoComingsoon": "",
    "dispLayerInfoFull": "",
    "dispLayerInfo": "/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/21,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/102,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/106,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/03,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/02,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/14,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/105,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/11,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/17,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/107,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/18,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/108,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/20,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/19,/ftop/uq/women/menu/sale/09",
    "_": "1589090253243"
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0",
    "Accept": "text/html, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    names = [name.get_text(strip=True) for name in soup.select("dt.name")]
    prices = [price.get_text(strip=True) for price in soup.select(
        "dd.price.fr-alias-primary--color01")]
    with open("data.csv", 'w', newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["Name", "Price"])
        writer.writerows(zip(names, prices))


main("https://www.uniqlo.com/jp/store/feature/uq/alias/v2/ajaxAliasItem.jsp")
```

Comment: Is there a way to write this into a output csv file?

Comment: @ChadHighfill you welcome. btw `csv` version updated.

Comment: can I ask two things 1) where did you find the displaylayInfo? Also I take it the URL in the request.gets is coming from displaylayinfo?

Comment: I ask, becuase I want to do this for mens and kids. I think I need understand the params part. Then I get the rest of the scirpt.

Answer (score 0):

For scraping product prices I usually use selenium because you usually need to wait a bit for the page to load and use headless browsers. Here is an example I have hosted in Google Colab https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-2WNuanlMit-Bqasi_FsB_q9v1QXs7qz?usp=sharing:

```py
url = 'https://www.uniqlo.com/jp/store/feature/uq/sale/women/'

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)

cls = lambda ele, cls: ele.find_element_by_class_name(cls)
tag = lambda ele, tag: ele.find_element_by_tag_name(tag)

items = [
    {'product': cls(item, 'name').text,
     'price': cls(item, 'price').text,
     'link': tag(cls(item, 'name'), 'a').get_attribute('href'),
     'timestamp': int(time.time())}
    for item in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('unit')
]

# print to a pretty json string
import json
# print(json.dumps(items, indent=4))

# export to csv
import csv

def write_csv(path, data, mode='w'):
    '''
    Append a csv with a dictionary keys as column headers
    Args:
        path (str): Path to the csv file
        data (dict): Dictionary with keys as column headers
                     and values as column data
        mode (str): open() mode, w, r, etc. Default: 'w'
    '''
    with open(path, mode) as file:
        # set the field names to the keys of the dictionary
        fieldnames = list(data[0].keys())
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        # write the header if the file is new
        if file.tell() == 0:
            writer.writeheader()
        # write the rows
        writer.writerows(data)

# write the csv, you can append 
write_csv('uniqlo_w.csv', items)
```

Output (csv):

[image]

If you want to append daily prices to the file, you can add the argumet `mode='a'` to the `write_csv()` function

Comment: Hi Tenacious, how would I run the first part on pycharm windows? I think the first part is linux based.

Comment: @ChadHighfill no need to use `selenium`, check below answer.

Comment: Figured out I needed to download chromdriver and make an executable path.